# having problem in running my npm start on my IDE terminal

Tags: node.js, reactjs

i am having problem in running my node app. i am getting this error whenever i run npm start from my termineal.
please i need help.

requireStack: []
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! nasa-project-api@1.0.0 start: `node src/server.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the nasa-project-api@1.0.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\USER\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache_logs\2022-09-15T09_15_58_848Z-debug.log
PS C:\Users\USER\Desktop\NASA-PROJECT\server>

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: `npm cache clean --force`

Step 2: Delete node_modules by $ `rm -rf node_modules package-lock.json folder` or delete it manually by going into the directory and right-click > delete / move to trash. Also, delete package-lock.json file too.

Step 3: `npm install`

To start again, `npm start`

This worked for me. Hopes it works for you too.

PS: If it is still there, kindly check the error it is displaying in red and act accordingly. This error is specific to node.js environment.